# M2 - Best practice for adding custom less file in Custom Theme for CMS Static Block

Tags: magento2.3.4, cms-block, less, custom-theme

I just created custom theme, i have followed a number of guides to properly setting up `.less` files in a custom theme and nothing seems to be working.

Where should i place less file for cms custom block,

`_theme.less` **or** `_extend.less` **or** `_module.less` **or** `create Magento_cms->web->css`

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

The last one (create Magento_cms->web->css), create _extend.less the for common CMS pages styles and own less style file in the page too differ by design and styles and import it to extend for example. Don't forget to make grunt exec after you'll add and import the file

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328503/57334